# Call a python function that create a file in c

Tags: python, c

I have this simple python function that create a file:

**kmer_counter.py**

```
def counter(k):

  list_kmer = []
  freq = {}

  reader = open("out/clean_read.txt", 'r')

  while True:
    line = reader.readline().rstrip()

    if not line:
      break

    for i in range(0, len(line) - k + 1):
      kmer = line[i : i + k]

      if kmer in freq:
        freq[kmer] += 1
      else:
        freq[kmer] = 1

  reader.close()

  freq = {key:val for key, val in freq.items() if val != 1}

  writer = open("out/kmer.txt", 'w')

  for key in freq.keys():
    writer.write(key + '\n')

  writer.close()
```

I try to call them in a C program using the `Python.h` header file. I don't have any kind of error but at the end of the main, the file is not created.
This is the `main.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
    #include <Python/Python.h>
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    #include <Python.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
#endif

int main(void) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* myModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char *) "kmer_counter");
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
    PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char *) "counter");

    PyObject* args = PyUnicode_FromString("5");
    PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(myFunction, args);

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

For compiling the file, I use the flag `-I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7`.

I see different question about this argument but I don't find any correct solution for this problem.

This is the content of the file `clean_read.txt`:

```
ACCAG
CCAGTG
GTGAAC
CAGTGA
ACCAGT
TGAACG
GAACGGTA
CAGTGTA
AACGGTA
GAACGG
AGTGAACG
AACGGT
CAGTGAA
TGAACGGTA
```

## EDIT

I add the following lines of code after `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` but it doesn't print anything.

```
if (myResult) { 
  fputs("result: ", stderr); 
  PyObject_Print(myResult, stderr, 0); 
  putc('\n', stderr); 
}
else { 
    fputs("exception:\n", stderr);
    PyErr_PrintEx(0);
}
```

`strace`output at this [link](https://pastebin.com/DuZLDs3J)

After replace the my main code with the code in the first answer this is the output:

```
This is the report what it outputs:
main begins
Py_SetProgramName: ok
Py_Initialize: ok
PyUnicode_FromString('kmer_counter'): result: r
u'kmer_counter'
PyImport_Import(myModuleString): exception:
ImportError: No module named kmer_counter
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the Python code. It's not clear which lines belong to with `def`, `while`, or `for` block.

Comment: Does the Python code work on its own (without calling it from C)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I just edit the post with the indentation of the Python code. For the second comment: Yes, the python code works correctly.

Comment: I think your Python code is throwing an exception.  When you embed a Python interpreter into a C program like this, you have to report exceptions yourself.  Please add the following code immediately after the `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` line, rerun your program, and tell us its _complete and unedited_ new output: `if (myResult) { fputs("result: ", stderr); PyObject_Print(myResult, stderr, 0); putc('\n', stderr); } else { fputs("exception:\n", stderr); PyErr_PrintEx(0); }`

Comment: If you are on Linux, it would also be useful to see the _complete and unedited_ output of `strace ./yourprogram`, but this will be enormous, so please save it to a file (e.g. `strace ./yourprogram > syscall-trace.txt 2>&1`), upload the file somewhere, and tell us the URL of the uploaded file.  If you are on some other operating system, unfortunately I don't know of an equivalent.

Comment: In a production program, you need to check whether _each_ of those Python API calls returned NULL before going on to the next step, but if any of them had returned NULL, the next step would have crashed, so I don't think that's your immediate problem.

Comment: @zwol I just edit the question with your question. I don't know why it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @zwol  I thought that since the python file is in a different folder than the one in the C file, I put the path to get from the C file to the python file in the `PyUnicode_FromString` function but nothing has changed.

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man Please see the answer I just posted for more debugging advice.  Also please correct your example code to be the code you are actually using, because I just noticed that it won't even compile.

Comment: @zwol: "if any of them had returned NULL, the next step would have crashed" Not necessarily, since many APIs accept `NULL` inputs. For example, if `PyUnicode_FromString` returned `NULL`, then ironically, it would make the next line valid (because now it would have a `NULL` marker for end of varargs). The call itself would raise a `TypeError` for insufficient arguments, but it wouldn't crash. Similarly, `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` checks the callable for `NULL` and returns `NULL` itself (to indicate it raised a `SystemError`). Even at the C API layer, Python tries not to actually segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got at least two critical errors in your code, maybe more. You need to check the return values from all the functions you're calling, or you'll miss them.

The two immediately obvious problems are:

1. You're failing to pass the `NULL` sentinel that `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` requires; that call must pass a final argument of `NULL` to serve as a sentinel indicating where the variable length argument list ends. `PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(myFunction, args);` should be `PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(myFunction, args, NULL);`
2. Your function expects a single argument, `k`, that it uses in a manner that clearly expects it to be a Python `int`, but you're explicitly constructing a Python `str` instead; the moment `for i in range(0, len(line) - k + 1):` is reached, it would immediately raise a `TypeError`. `PyObject* args = PyUnicode_FromString("5");` should be `PyObject* args = PyLong_FromLong(5);` to produce the correct type.

In both cases, the error is on the final call for which you're not checking the return code; the type issue would raise a Python level exception bypassing the rest of the Python function, while the varargs error could do unpredictably terrible things. You need to be more disciplined about checking return values, and you need to pay closer attention to the API requirements.

Side-note: In this particular case, you could save some effort by using [`PyObject_CallFunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallFunction) to replace a decent amount of the code, including all the bad code. All of this:

```
PyObject* args = PyUnicode_FromString("5");
PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(myFunction, args);
```

could be replaced with:

```
PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunction(myFunction, "i", 5);
```

which simplifies the work (and reduces the number of objects leaked by one).

---

#### Update to address edit:

Looks like `kmer_counter.py` is neither in your working directory, nor anywhere else in `sys.path`. If you're running this from the command line, the simplest solution is to `cd` into the same directory as `kmer_counter.py` before running your executable (which need not be in the same directory). Another (somewhat hacky) solution is to create/expand the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the path that contains `kmer_counter.py`, e.g. in `bash` you might do (following the paths from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853322/call-a-python-function-that-create-a-file-in-c/55859139#comment98401057_55870163)):

```sh
PYTHONPATH=./src/prepros ./app
```

or as a two-liner (where the `export` only needs to be run once):

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=./src/prepros
./app
```

In any event, just to give you an idea of how much unnecessary work you're doing, here's your C code simplified to use as few API calls as possible (using [zwol's `check_PyAPI`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55870163/364696) to simplify error-checking, though in real code, you may want to handle some errors by means other than immediately dying with an error message):

```
int main(void) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();

    // Load module without needing to construct PyUnicode manually
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_ImportModule("kmer_counter");
    check_PyAPI("PyImport_ImportModule(\"kmer_counter\")", myModule);

    // Call function on module without needing to construct PyUnicode
    // or PyLong, and without needing to load the function itself
    PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallMethod(myModule, "counter", "i", 5);
    Py_DECREF(myModule);  // Done with module, release reference
    check_PyAPI("PyObject_CallMethod(myModule, \"counter\", \"i\", 5)", myResult);

    // Do whatever you want with successful result

    Py_DECREF(myResult); // Done with result, release reference

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Does the work of all five of the calls you made in two calls (I also added in `Py_DECREF`s just to police your reference counts); sure, if the various temporaries need to be reused, it might be worth making them once and using them over and over instead of letting the higher-level functions reconstruct `PyUnicode`s over and over or continually re-lookup the function in question. But when you're just getting started, let Python do a bit more of the work for you; optimize later (you're already going to be faster than Python level code by virtue of avoiding the bytecode interpreter overhead).

Comment: Did you mean `PyObject_CallFunction(myFunction, "i", 5)` there?

Comment: @zwol: Yeah, oops. Stupid copy-paste errors. Fixed now.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could use `PyObject_CallMethod` with a module object as the receiver.

Comment: @zwol: Yeah, the name implies it's for methods, but it's really just doing the `PyObject_GetAttrString` call on the "object" (a module in this case) then calling the result. It's just like plain attribute lookup, followed by calling the result, where plain attribute lookup happens to bind methods when appropriate, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

ShadowRanger's answer is correct as far as it goes, but your `strace` output indicates that your program never attempted to open any file named `kmer_counter.py`, which means the problem happened much earlier, possibly even within `Py_Initialize`.  It is time to apply a more aggressive debugging technique: logging the result of *every single operation* within `main`.  Please replace your entire test program with this code, build and run it, and report what it outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
    #include <Python/Python.h>
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    #include <Python.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
#endif

static void check_PyAPI(const char *fn, PyObject *rv)
{
  if (rv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: result: ", fn);
    PyObject_Print(rv, stderr, 0);
    putc('\n', stderr);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: exception:\n", fn);
    PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  setvbuf(stderr, 0, _IOLBF, 0); // ensure line-buffering for stderr
  fputs("main begins\n", stderr);

  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
  fputs("Py_SetProgramName: ok\n", stderr);

  Py_Initialize();
  fputs("Py_Initialize: ok\n", stderr);

  PyObject* myModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char *) "kmer_counter");
  check_PyAPI("PyUnicode_FromString('kmer_counter')", myModuleString);

  PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
  check_PyAPI("PyImport_Import(myModuleString)", myModule);

  PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule, (char *) "counter");
  check_PyAPI("PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule, 'counter')", myFunction);

  PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunction(myFunction, "i", 5);
  check_PyAPI("PyObject_CallFunction(myFunction, 'i', 5)", myResult);

  Py_Finalize();
  fputs("after Py_Finalize\n", stderr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edit the post with the output. As I said in a comment above, it does not seem to find the kmer_counter.py file that is in a different folder. The main one is in the `./app`, while the python file is at the path `./src/prepros/ `